# A problem related to the convergence of infinitely divisible distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, limits, convergence-divergence, levy-processes

We have a classic theorem about convergence of infinitely divisible (ID) distributions. Before, remember that we say that the ID random vector $X$ has a Lévy-Khintchine representation, for a suitable integrable function $c:\mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R$, if
\begin{equation}
    \varphi_X(u) = \exp \left\{ i a_c^\intercal u -  \frac{u ^\intercal \sigma u}{2} + \int_{\mathbb R^p} \left[e^{i u^\intercal x } - 1 - i u^\intercal x c(x)  \right] d\nu(x) \right\},\quad u \in \mathbb R^p,
\end{equation}
We denote this by $X\sim(a, \sigma, \nu)_c$.

The following classical theorem is given in [Sato](https://www.cambridge.org/br/universitypress/subjects/statistics-probability/probability-theory-and-stochastic-processes/levy-processes-and-infinitely-divisible-distributions?format=HB&isbn=9780521553025), Theorem 8.7:

> Let $c: \mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that:
> \begin{equation}\label{I}\tag{c} c(x)= 1+ o(|x|)\quad \hbox{ as }\,\,
>  x \to 0\\ c(x)=O(1/|x|)\quad \hbox{ as }\,\, x \to \infty.
>  \end{equation}
>
> Suppose $X\sim(a_{n}, \sigma_n, \nu_n)_c$ be a sequence of $ID$
> random variables and $X$ some random variable. Then $X_n
>  \overset{d}{\to} X$ iff $X$ is ID and has a Lévy-Khintchine
> representation triplet $(a, \sigma, \nu)_c$ satisfying:
>
> 1. For any continuity set $E$ (i.e. $\nu(\partial E)=0$) with $0\notin \bar{E}$, $$\nu_n(E) \to \nu(E), \quad (n \to \infty)$$
> 2. For any $\epsilon > 0$, defining the symmetric nonnegative-definite matrices $\sigma_{n, \varepsilon}$ by
>    \begin{equation}
>         \left\langle u, \sigma_{n, \varepsilon} u\right\rangle :=\left\langle u, \sigma_n u\right\rangle+\int_{|x| \leq
>    > \varepsilon}\langle u, x\rangle^2 \nu_n(dx) . \end{equation} we have
>    \begin{equation}\label{II}\tag{II} \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \limsup_{n
>    > \rightarrow \infty}\left|\left\langle u, \sigma_{n, \varepsilon}
>     u\right\rangle-\langle u, \sigma u\rangle\right|=0 \quad \text { for }
>     u \in \mathbb{R}^n. \end{equation}
> 3. $a_{n} \to a$, as $n \to \infty$.

I want to use this Theorem to show another version of the same result (please, see the *fact A* from the firts two page of this [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02951448)). For convenience, let's print the paper's statement specifying items 1, 2 and 3, analogous to Theorem 8.7. Item 2 is marked with a red rectangle to indicate the difference between versions of the same result.

[image]

- First, note that the paper uses $c(x)= \frac{1}{1+|x|^2}$. It's easy to show that $c(x)= \frac{1}{1+|x|^2}$ satisfies (\ref{I}).
- So, Items 1 and 3 of the paper (analogous to Theorem 8.7 in Sato's book) are obtained directly.
- Thus, it remaims to show that the second item on the paper marked with the red rectangle is equivalent to (\ref{II}). For convenience, we rewrite it.
  \begin{equation}\label{2}\tag{2}
  \sigma_n + \int_{\mathbb R^p} \frac{xx'}{1+ |x|^2}d \nu_n \to \sigma + \int_{\mathbb R^p} \frac{xx'}{1+ |x|^2} d \nu
  \end{equation}

**Problem 1**

*How to show that (\ref{II}) and (\ref{2}) are equivalent?*

**Considerations**

Sato says that equation (8.20) (page number 43 from his book) given by:
\begin{equation}\label{II'}\tag{II'}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left[\left\langle u, \sigma_n u\right\rangle+\int_{|x| \leq \varepsilon}\langle u, x\rangle^2 \nu_n(dx)\right] = \langle u, \sigma u \rangle, \quad \forall u \in \mathbb R^p
\end{equation}
is equivalent to (\ref{II}). Note that (\ref{II'}) is also true for $\liminf$ instead of $\limsup$.
If we are willing to assume that (\ref{2}) is equivalent to

\begin{equation}\label{2'}\tag{2'}
\langle u , \sigma_n u \rangle + \int_{\mathbb R^p} \frac{\langle u, x\rangle^2}{1+ |x|^2}d \nu_n \to \langle u , \sigma u \rangle + \int_{\mathbb R^p} \frac{\langle u, x\rangle^2}{1+ |x|^2} d \nu, \quad \forall u \in \mathbb R^p
\end{equation}

So maybe it's easier to show the equivalence between (\ref{II'}) and (\ref{2'}). In this case, Problem 1 would be rewritten as:

**Problem 1'**

*How to show that (\ref{II'}) and (\ref{2'}) are equivalent?*

**A Third Version**

Another approach might be to use Theorem 7.7 from Kallenberg's Book (see JGWang's comment). First, Corollary 7.6 below shows that an ID random vector has a canonical representation - i.e. the case $c(x)= \mathbf{1}_{D}$, where $D=\{x: |x|\leq 1\}$. To show this, Kallenberg shows and uses a third version of the same Theorem 8.7 with some truncated version. Below is the print. I got by omitting statements that are not of interest to us. (Just be careful noting that the parameters are different. Just to situate the reader, the parameter $a$ and $\sigma$, in the version of Sato's book, correspond respectively to the parameter $b$ and $a$ of Kallemberg's book. The Levy measures in both cases are denoted by $\nu$ and the convergence is the same in the three versions.)
[image]

But this version for me is more challenging, because it involves $h$ and I don't know how to deal with it. So a third question that is also interesting (but not as urgent for me) is:

**Problem 2 (not as urgent but might be helpful)**

*How are the three versions related?*

Help!

Comment: Regarding your problems, please refer B. V. Gnedenko $\&$ A. N. Kolmogorov, *Limit distributions for sums of Independent Random Variables*, Addison-Wesley Publishing Company, (1968), Th.19.2, pp.87-- and   O. Kallenberg, *Foundations of Modern Probability*, 3ed., Springer Verlag, 2021. Th.7.7, pp.152.

Comment: Please clarify your problems as Problem1, Problem2,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{gather*}
 \text{(I): For any continuity set $E$(i.e. $\nu(\partial E)=0$) with }
 0\notin \bar{E},\\
 \nu_n(E) \to \nu(E), \quad \text{as } n\to\infty.  \tag{I}\\
 \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\varlimsup_{n\to\infty}\Big[\langle u,\sigma_n u \rangle +\int_{|x|\le\epsilon}\langle u,x\rangle^2 \nu_n(\mathrm{d}x)\Big]
 =\langle u,\sigma u\rangle. \tag{II'} \\
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\Big[\langle u,\sigma_n u \rangle+ \int_{\mathbb{R}^p}
 \frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu_n(\mathrm{d}x)\Big]
 = \langle u,\sigma u \rangle+ \int_{\mathbb{R}^p}
 \frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu(\mathrm{d}x) \tag{2'}\\
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\Big[\langle u,\sigma_n u \rangle+ \int_{\mathbb{R}^p}
 \frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu_n(\mathrm{d}x) 
 -\int_{\mathbb{R}^p}\frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu(\mathrm{d}x) \Big]
 = \langle u,\sigma u \rangle.
 \tag{2"}
\end{gather*}

The following will prove that
\begin{equation*}
 (I) + (II^\prime) \Longleftrightarrow (I) +(2') \quad
 (\text{i.e., } (I) + (II^\prime) \Longleftrightarrow (I) +(2")). \tag{3} 
\end{equation*}
From (I),
\begin{equation}
 \sup_n \nu_n(|x|\ge \epsilon)\le C_1(\epsilon),\quad \forall \epsilon>0. \tag{4}
\end{equation}
From (II'),
\begin{equation*}
 \sup_n\int_{|x|\le\epsilon} \frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2} \nu_n(\mathrm{d}x)\le C_2(u, \epsilon),\quad \forall \epsilon>0, u\in\mathbb{R}^p.  
\end{equation*}
Combining above and (4),
\begin{equation*}
 \sup_n\int_{\mathbb{R}^p}
 \frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu_n(\mathrm{d}x)\le C_3(u),\quad \forall  u\in\mathbb{R}^p.  \tag{5}
\end{equation*}
(5) holds too from (2').

Now, we are ready to prove (3). In the following proof, suppose the $(2')$ or $(II')$ holds, therefore (5) holds too. Subtracting the left side of (II') and (2"),
\begin{align*}
 &\Big[\langle u,\sigma_n u \rangle+ \int_{\mathbb{R}^p}
 \frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu_n(\mathrm{d}x) 
 -\int_{\mathbb{R}^p}\frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu(\mathrm{d}x) \Big]\\
 &\quad -\Big[\langle u,\sigma_n u \rangle +\int_{|x|\le\epsilon}\langle u,x\rangle^2 \nu_n(\mathrm{d}x)\Big]  = E_1+E_2+E_3,    \tag{6}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 E_1 &= \int_{|x|>\epsilon}
 \frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu_n(\mathrm{d}x) 
 -\int_{|x|>\epsilon}\frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu(\mathrm{d}x) \\
 E_2 &=-\int_{|x|\le\epsilon}\frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu(\mathrm{d}x)   \\
 E_3 &=\int_{|x|\le\epsilon}\frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu_n(\mathrm{d}x)
 - \int_{|x|\le\epsilon}\langle u,x\rangle^2 \nu_n(\mathrm{d}x)\\
 &\quad \epsilon \in\{a>0:\nu(\{x:|x|=a\})=0\}
\end{align*}

Now from (1),
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{n\to\infty}|E_1| &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big|\int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu_n(\mathrm{d}x)
 -\int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu(\mathrm{d}x) \Big| \\
 &=0, \quad  \forall u\in\mathbb{R}^p.  \tag{7}
\end{align*}
Since $\int_{\mathbb{R}^p}(|x|^2\wedge 1)\nu(\mathrm{d}x)<\infty $ and $\nu(\{0\})=0$, then
\begin{gather*}
 |E_2|=\int_{|x|\le\epsilon} \frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu(\mathrm{d}x)
 \le |u|^2 \int_{|x|\le\epsilon}|x|^2\nu(\mathrm{d}x),\\
 \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}|E_2|=0. \tag{8}
\end{gather*}
\begin{align*}
 |E_3| &=\Big|\int_{|x|\le\epsilon}\langle u,x\rangle^2 \nu_n(\mathrm{d}x)
 -\int_{|x|\le\epsilon} \frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu_n(\mathrm{d}x)\Big|\\
 & =\int_{|x|\le\epsilon} \frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2|x|^2 }{1+|x|^2}\nu_n(\mathrm{d}x) \le \epsilon^2\sup_n\int_{\mathbb{R}^p}\frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu_n(\mathrm{d}x)\\
&\le \epsilon^2C_3(u),
\end{align*}
by (5) and
\begin{equation*} \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\varlimsup_{n\to\infty}|E_3|=0 \tag{9}
\end{equation*}

Using (7)-(9) and (6), got
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\varlimsup_{n\to\infty}\biggl|\Big[\langle u,\sigma_n u \rangle+ \int_{\mathbb{R}^p}
\frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu_n(\mathrm{d}x) 
-\int_{\mathbb{R}^p}\frac{\langle u,x\rangle^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu(\mathrm{d}x) \Big]\\
&\qquad\quad -\Big[\langle u,\sigma_n u \rangle +\int_{|x|\le\epsilon}\langle u,x\rangle^2 \nu_n(\mathrm{d}x)\Big]\biggr|=0,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{equation*}
 (I) + (II^\prime) \Longleftrightarrow (I) +(2') \quad
  (\text{i.e., } (I) + (II^\prime) \Longleftrightarrow (I) +(2")). 
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thanks for the second answer. I'm honestly having a lot of trouble demonstrating that, once $u$ is fixed, $(II')$ implies $(*)\,\,\sup_n \int_{|x|\leq \epsilon} \frac{(u'x)^2}{ 1+|x|^2}\nu_n(dx) \leq C_2(\epsilon)$, for all $\epsilon $. I understand well that $\frac{(u'x)^2}{1+|x|^2}\leq (u'x)^2$. This implies $\int_{|x|\leq \epsilon} \frac{(u'x)^2}{1+|x|^2}\nu_n(dx) \leq \int_{|x|\leq \epsilon} (u'x)^2\nu_n(dx)$. But I can't use the limits $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \overline{\lim}_{n \to \infty}$ in $(II')$ to conclude $(*)$. Can you fix $u$ and $\epsilon$ and help me get this part done?

Comment: @AndréGoulart Thank you for your question. In new version, replace the ($*$), I prove the (5). Also, in the proof of (9), use (5) only but ($*$). In fact, I couldn't prove ($*$) right now, thank you to mention  this.

Comment: Okay, I understand that we can get to (5) using (2'), but this just shows that $(I) + (2') \implies (I) + (II')$. In order to show the converse, I need to show $(*)$ starting from $(II')$. It is this reciprocal that interests me most. If I could change the order of limits $\epsilon \to 0 $ $n \to \infty$, the problem would be solved.

Comment: Let me try. Fix $u$ and $\epsilon>0$. Define $x_{mk}:= u'\sigma_k u + \int_{|x|\leq \epsilon/m} (u'x)^2 \nu_k(dx)$. Note that $(II')$ implies $\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k\geq n} x_{mk}= u'\sigma u$. Since all convergent sequence is bounded, we have $$x_{mk}\leq \sup_{k\geq n} x_{mk} \leq C(\epsilon), \,\, \forall (m,n), k \geq n$$ 
Taking $m=1$ and $k=n$, we have $u'\sigma_n u + \int_{|x|\leq \epsilon} (u'x)^2 \nu_n(dx)\leq C(\epsilon)$ for all $n$.  If this is true,  we can conclude $(*)$.

Comment: Thank you for your problems and comments. Now I add some words in my proof: "Now, we are ready to prove (3). *In the following proof, suppose the $(2')$ or $(II')$ holds, therefore (5) holds too. * Subtracting ". Hope it could be understanded by you.